# when clicked on connect on new database option in dbeaver which event is triggered in windows

Tags: database, windows, automation

when clicked on connect on new database option in DBeaver which event is triggered in windows.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/X90zj.png)

I want to hold that option till my session ends I am trying use that for automation. can somone get me some idea how should hold it